# Search for a number then record its "coded" value

Tags: excel

[image]I have some code I have used from a previous problem. It searches a library for a string than records all possible matches of the subtext (what I am searching for). I want to change it to record the matching numbers coded value or the next column over. This is a repeated process so my library would have to record the same value multiple times in random order.

This is the code I used for my previous problem...
    =INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A:$A)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E14,$A:$A))),COLUMN(A:A)))

I want this code to extract only the second column of information that goes with the value of the first column. I would like it to look like this when it's done. I'm just recording the next column over instead of the column I'm searching in.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Combination of Index() and Match() may be useful here. Here is an example:

```
Data:
    A      B      C
1  ID    Qty    Desc
2  10     2      Nut
3  20     4      Bolt
4  30     6      Washer

=INDEX(C2:C4,MATCH(<search-for>,A2:A4,0))
```

This formula for the table will return the description for the item that matches the  value in the ID column.